# Structuring BigQuery on trigrams with multiple inputs

Tags: google-bigquery

Presently, thanks to help from the answerer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33861460/structuring-bigquery-with-large-array-of-data-as-input), I am able to successfully query a word, and get a list of the most popular follow-on words. For example, using the word "great", I am able to get a list of up 10 words in the following format:

```
SELECT second, SUM(cell.page_count) total 
FROM [publicdata:samples.trigrams] 
WHERE first = "great"
group by 1
order by 2 desc
limit 10
```

With the output:

```
second     total     
------------------
deal       3048832   
and        1689911   
,          1576341   
a          1019511   
number     984993    
many       875974    
importance 805215    
part       739409    
.          700694    
as         628978
```

What I am currently having trouble figuring out how is how to do this query for multiple words *automatically* (as opposed to calling a query on a separate word each time) so that I could possibly have a output such as:

```
"great"     total     "new_word_1"           new_total_1 ... "new_word_N"     new_total_N
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
deal       3048832    "new_follow_on_word1"  123456      ... "follow_on_N1"   234567
and        1689911    "new_follow_on_word2"  12345       ... "follow_on_N2"   123456
```

Where essentially I could call `N` number of words in a single query (for example, `new_word_1` is a totally different word like "baseball", with **no** relation to "great"), and getting the total counts related to each word on a different column.

Additionally, after learning about the BigQuery's [pricing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18834196/google-bigquery-pricing), I am also having trouble figuring out how to limit the total data queried as much possible. I can think of using only the latest data (say, such as 2010 onwards) and 2 alphanumeric outputs per word, but may be missing more obvious limiters

Any help on this is much appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put multiple first words in the same query, but it will need to compute top 10 following words separately, and then join together the results. Here is an example for "great" and "baseball"

```
SELECT word1, total1, word2, total2 FROM
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() rowid1, word1, total1 FROM (
SELECT second as word1, SUM(cell.page_count) total1 
FROM [publicdata:samples.trigrams] 
WHERE first = "great"
group by 1
order by 2 desc
limit 10)) a1
JOIN
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() rowid2, word2, total2 FROM (
SELECT second as word2, SUM(cell.page_count) total2 
FROM [publicdata:samples.trigrams] 
WHERE first = "baseball"
group by 1
order by 2 desc
limit 10)) a2
ON a1.rowid1 = a2.rowid2
```

Comment: I've just deleted my answer as I realized i missed top 10 requirement